# starting ember-cli app with docker-compose up

Tags: ember-cli, dockerfile, docker-compose

I'm trying to run my ember-cli app using

'docker-compose up' command, but getting the following error..

```
front-end_1 | Future versions of Ember CLI will not support v0.10.25. 
Please update to Node 0.12 or io.js.
front-end_1 | version: 1.13.8
front-end_1 | You have to be inside an ember-cli project in order to  
use the serve command.
```

Here is my Dockerfile

```
#https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

# Create user docker so we don't have to run everything as root.
RUN useradd -d /home/docker -m -s /bin/bash docker

# Install dependencies.
RUN sudo apt-get update -q && apt-get install -qy\
  autoconf \
  autotools-dev \
  build-essential\
  chrpath \
  curl \
  git\
  libbz2-dev \
  libcurl4-openssl-dev \
  libexpat-dev \
  libfontconfig1-dev \
  libncurses-dev \
  libssl-dev \
  m4\
  nodejs-legacy \
  npm \
  python-dev \
  ruby-compass \
  texinfo \
  zlib1g-dev

#install homebrew
USER docker
RUN  ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew/go/install)"

ENV PATH=$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$HOME/local/m4/bin:$PATH
ENV MANPATH=$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/man:$MANPATH
ENV INFOPATH=$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/info:$INFOPATH

RUN $HOME/.linuxbrew/bin/brew install watchman

USER root

#install npm packages

RUN npm install -g --save bower \
  ember-cli

# Clean up after apt
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# Code volume should be mounted here.
VOLUME /code
#ADD ./code /code

EXPOSE 4200

# Use baseimage-docker's init system so CMD doesn't have PID 1.
# https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker#running-a-one-shot-command-in-the-container
# ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/my_init", "--quiet", "--skip-startup-files", "--skip-runit", "--"]

# Open shell as user docker by default.
CMD ["su", "docker"]

WORKDIR /code

# run ember server on container start

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/ember"]

CMD ["server"]
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
front-end:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
```

Could you pls let me know how I can fix this issue? also, I'm sure I can improve/optimise my Dockerfle..any feedback on my Dockerfile would be great as well..

Comment: Some notes on your Dockerfile: 1) cleaning up after apt-get install in a separate RUN command doesn't shrink the image at all , it needs to happen in the same RUN step as the apt-get install 2) you probably dont want `VOLUME /code`,   you can create a host volume at runtime.  3) You have two `CMD` entries, but you can only have one. The first one isn't doing anything.

Comment: thx!!.cleaned it all up and saved about 40MB..still my image is about 550MB though..

Comment: Ya, the cleanup doesn't do all that much (I rarely do it).  Other things you can do to reduce the image side: 1) use a different base image, the debian base images tend to be quite a bit smaller than ubuntu 2) You could try to avoid installer homebrew and find a way to build a binary of `watchman` in a container. Then just curl to install the binary.

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happening is that `docker-compose` is preserving the volume you're creating with `VOLUMES /code` instead of using the host volume.  Try running `docker-compose rm -f` to remove the old containers, removing the `VOLUMES /code` from the `Dockerfile`, and trying to run `up` again.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got this working..

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:wheezy

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

# Install dependencies.
RUN apt-get update -q && apt-get install -qy\
  autoconf \
  autotools-dev \
  build-essential\
  chrpath \
  curl \
  git\
  libbz2-dev \
  libcurl4-openssl-dev \
  libexpat-dev \
  libfontconfig1-dev \
  libncurses-dev \
  libssl-dev \
  m4\
  python-dev \
  ruby-compass \
  texinfo \
  zlib1g-dev

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | bash -

RUN apt-get install -qy nodejs \
  npm

RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN git clone https://github.com/facebook/watchman.git \
    && cd watchman \
    && git checkout v3.1 \
    && ./autogen.sh \
    && ./configure \
    && make \
    && make install

#install npm packages
RUN npm install -g bower \
  ember-cli

EXPOSE 4200

VOLUME /code
WORKDIR /code

CMD ["ember", "server"]
```

and my docker-compose.ml

```
front-end:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
    volumes:
      - ./code:/code
```

now, I can start my ember-cli app using 'docker-compose up' command.

However this docker image is about 600MB..Is there any way I could shrink the size of the image?

Comment: Are you install node twice?  It seems like you apt-get install it, but you also download the source?

Comment: If you only need all the `autoconf`, and `-dev` packages for building watchman, you could install them in the same RUN line, and `apt-get remove --purge` them at the same time.